# Xamarin Forms - Listview grouping issue

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

### How can I make a Xamarin.forms listview with a grouping with a subsection column like this:

headername
subheadername1
id description state status - column label
(Data binded into respective columns)
subheadername2
Id    description value status - column label2
(Data binded into    respective columns)

========================================================================

I tried every example of every listview for Xamarin.forms grouping on the internet and i'm still not getting the output that I wanted. I'm a beginner and new at Xamarin.forms and XAML and i'm still stuck at this problem.
Edit:

```
<ContentPage>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.Header>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="devicename"  BackgroundColor="#87cefa"/>
                <Label Text="Digital Inputs" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="#ADD8E6" />
                <Label Text="Analog Inputs" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="#ADD8E6" />

                <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="ID"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Label Text="Input Description" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Label Text="Input State" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Label Text="Status" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="1" ></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="hello" ></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="world" ></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Text ="hello" ></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

[screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmDWA.png)

Comment: 1. you don't have IsGroupingEnabled turned on . 2. for some reason you're setting Grid.Row and Column, even though you don't have a Grid . 3. You have an empty StackLayout at the end that does nothing.   4. I'd suggest you try to enable grouping with a simple TextCell, and once you have that working then try creating your own ViewCell

Comment: i'll enable it wait.

Comment: Editied the code.

Comment: What's the problem?  "not getting the output that I wanted" doesn't really explain the problem.  What specifically is not working like you intended? Can you post a screenshot?  And again, I'd suggest you start with a much simpler scenario, get that working, and the build on it instead of starting with a very complex use case.

Comment: The rows should be divided into subsections containing the columns and group header name is the device name. Added screenshot.

Comment: @BastiArcega, Please refer this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/

Comment: Is it this view you are looking for? ( I blogged about it ) http://depblog.weblogs.us/2017/09/24/xamarin-forms-repeaterview/